# Input from a method gets stuck in java

Tags: java

In this method, it prompts the user to enter the value of their insured home. For some reason, it is getting stuck when the user inputs

```
static double promptHomeInsVal(){
        double homeInsVal;
        className promptHomeInsVal = new className();
        do{
            do{
                System.out.printf("%nPlease enter the insured value of your home:  ");
                homeInsVal = promptHomeInsVal.input.nextDouble();
                validateNumber(!promptHomeInsVal.input.hasNextDouble());
            }while(promptHomeInsVal.repeat == true);
            homeInsVal = promptHomeInsVal.input.nextDouble();
            if(homeInsVal <= 0){
                System.out.println("The insured value of your home cannot be less than or equal to 0. ");
                promptHomeInsVal.repeat = true;
            }
            else{
                promptHomeInsVal.repeat = false;
                System.out.println("Home insurance value == " + homeInsVal);
            }
        }while(promptHomeInsVal.repeat == true);

        return homeInsVal;
    }
```

Here is validateNumber()

```
static void validateNumber(boolean repeat){
        className validateNumber = new className();
        if(repeat == true){
            System.out.println("Warning:  You entered an invalid integer or floating-point value. ");
        }
    }
```

When the prompt comes up "Please enter the insured value of your home: " it is suppose to take the input and move on. Right now, it is getting stuck

Answer (score 0):

I feel that a significant part of the code is missing, and as far as I can see the problem should be in that part of the code. You should include into your question the code of the class `className` (which seems to be an error by itself).

In addition to that, I see some minor coding style mistakes in your code. You did not ask for such advice, but let me note that `anyBooleanVariable == true` is just the same as `anyBooleanVariable`.

Also `validateNumber` is the name of a method and the same time the name of a local variable inside the same named method. It is possible, but this is confusing and not a recommended practice.